# How can i run a piece of code when user clicks on save button in a form in Odoo 13?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, odoo

I have a function as shown below, I am sending a mail to X and currently, I have created a button to send it but I want it to be sent once the user clicks on the save button in a form view and the actual functionality of the save button should work as it always does.

```
def action_send_card(self):
        print("sending")
        template_id = self.env.ref('germi_leave_plugin.leave_email_template').id
        self.env['mail.template'].browse(template_id).send_mail(self.id,force_send=True)
```

Comment: You have to override `create()` and `write()`, because both methods can be called from the save button.

Comment: will the form still be saved if I override them? like I want both the things to happen save it in DB as the save button by default performs and also send a mail

Comment: If you do it right, it will work just as used to. So make super calls and return expected values (like the super call return value).

Answer (score 0):

you have to ovrride the write function and there call your function just pay attention after calling your function you should use super() or if you saved manually something on your table you should return that record

```
def write(self, vals):
    print("sending")
    template_id = self.env.ref('germi_leave_plugin.leave_email_template').id
    self.env['mail.template'].browse(template_id).send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
    return super(self).write(vals)
```

Comment: Rather super() first, *then* send the template, because you would want to send the latest values in the template, not the old ones before you saved.

Comment: yes you're right that was my mistake ;)